# How to refresh WebElement in Selenium Webdriver without reload page?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I need  to refresh WebElement in Selenium Webdriver without reload page.
When i use a while, the text of the page element is constantly updated because it is a chat, but the loop carries only the same text.

```
while (driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("chat")).Count() > 0)
            {
                {
                    var element = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("_chat")).Text;
                    Console.WriteLine(element);
                }
            }
```

I am using a C# project.
Thanks!

Comment: The loop will get the number of elements with `chat` class at the beginning of the loop and then iterate that many times. If there are any new elements added after the loop initiated those won't be considered in the current loop. If that's what you are looking for then please wrap your loop with another loop and define how many times you want to run this loop.'

Comment: Please, how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i use java
If you get element outdated errors
you can use it

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.name("_chat")));
```

Instead of

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElement(By.name("_chat"))));
```

not use driver.findElement

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
           while (driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("chat")).Count() > 0)
            {
                {
                    var element = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("_chat")).Text;
                    Console.WriteLine(element);
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: I noticed that selenium normally updates the text of the first user that was found when starting, but does not update the text of new messages from other users.

Comment: I think we might need the screen and the html in order to assist you further.